# can nameko use python3?

Tags: python-3.x, nameko

nameko run --config ./foobar.yaml my_app

the above line defaults to to running my_app with python2. can I change it to python3? the documentation doesn't show this option but considering you get get nameko with pip3 it sounds reasonable.

Comment: how are you installing nameko? are you using a python3 virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Nameko works with Python 3.

You just need to execute `nameko run` in an environment where Python 3 is the default (or only) interpreter.